# java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable. key expected Parcelable but value was a java.util.ArrayList

Tags: android

what is the reason of the below error

```
Key Object_list expected Parcelable but value was a java.util.ArrayList.  The default value <null> was returned.
```

this is full code

```
public class SingleObjectActivity extends Activity
{
    public static final String OBJECT_LIST = "Object_list";
    private ArrayList<Listitem> Objects;
    public ImageView imgview;
    private Listitem listObjects;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.singleobject);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.funnyimage);

        if (extras.containsKey(OBJECT_LIST)) {
            this.listObjects = extras.getParcelable(OBJECT_LIST);
        } else {
            this.listObjects = null;
        }

        if (listObjects != null) {
            Picasso.
                    with(getApplicationContext()).
                    load(listObjects.getUrl())
                            //load()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                    .fit()
                    .noFade()
                    .into(imgview);

        }
    }
}
```

sending intent

```
        ArrayList<Listitem> personArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        personArrayList.add(new Listitem(item.getOrder(), item.getId(), item.getUrl(), item.getUserName(), item.getLikes()));

        Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext,SingleObjectActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Object_list", personArrayList);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mcontext.startActivity(intent);
```

edit 4

```
        ArrayList<Listitem> items = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Object_list");
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.funnyimage);

     /*   if (extras != null) {
            Objects = extras.getParcelableArrayList(OBJECT_LIST);
        } else {
            Objects = new ArrayList<Listitem>();
        }*/

        if (extras.containsKey(OBJECT_LIST)) {
//            this.listObjects = extras.getParcelable(OBJECT_LIST);
         //   this.listObjects = (Listitem) extras.getParcelable(OBJECT_LIST);
            this.Objects=  extras.getParcelableArrayList("Object_list");


        } else {
            this.Objects = null;
        }

        if (this.listObjects != null) {
            Picasso.
                    with(getApplicationContext()).
                    load(this.listObjects.getUrt())
                            //load()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                    .fit()
                    .noFade()
                    .into(imgview);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Sar's answer is correct, assuming of course that `ListItem` implements the `Parcelable` interface.

Comment: @PPartisan i am checking it now and yes it parcelable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When sending your `ArrayList`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context ,TargetActivity.class);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Object_list", personArrayList);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

When receiving your `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<ListItem> items = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Object_list");
```

Note that this is not the same as `getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList()`. Currently, I believe you are incorrectly writing

```
Bundle extras = geIntent().getExtras();
extras.getParcelableArrayList("Object_list");
```

Also, `ListItem`, despite implementing `Parcelable`, does not copy all of its values. This probably isn't causing your issue but is worth keeping in mind.

Comment: but how to get the value of url ? please check my edit when applying your code

Comment: @Moudiz As I believe  you've already been told, you access the relevant index in your `ArrayList` with the `get()` method to return a `ListItem` object, to which you can call `getUrl()`. It's impossible to tell which index you want from your code however. If you just wanted to test it out, try accessing index `0` -  `listItems.get(0).getUrl()`.

Comment: hi man i am still having problem in my code , can you assist me?

Comment: perfect explanation

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do :

```
 intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Object_list", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) personArrayList);
```

and get inside intended activity like :

```
 this.Objects= extras.getParcelableArrayList("Object_list");
```

Make sure that Listitem class is implementing Parcelable.

Comment: there is no `getParcelableArrayListExtra`

Comment: @Moudiz There is, it's [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String)) in the documentation. Note you want to use `getIntent().getParcelbleArrayListExtra()`, and not `getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayListExtra()`

Comment: You can use extras.getParcelableArrayList() method

Comment: @Sar still i get error using it             `this.listObjects= extras.getParcelableArrayList("Object_list");`  required lisitem found arraylist .. is it maybe problem in listobjects because its declared listitem ?

Comment: You should do 
this.Objects
 not
 this.listObjects

Comment: @sar okay... then in picasso to get the image                     `load(listObjects.getUrl())` how to get listobject ?

Comment: Use Objects.get(position).getUrt() for getting particular item's url from list

Comment: and how do i get position?

Comment: Do you want only a single ListItem in SingleObjectActivity not all the list?

Comment: in my scenario i want only the url passed from the intent

Comment: Then there is no need to pass the whole list of items. You should pass only the url as string.

Comment: @Sar later ill be sending another things. why I am not able to get the arraylist ?

Comment: You should pass only  intent.putExtra("key", item.getUrl);

Comment: can you show me in an exmaple because i am lost now

Answer (score 0):

You may try this :

To get `ArrayList` from `extras`

```
this.listObjects = (Listitem) extras.getParcelable(OBJECT_LIST);
```

Comment: @Moudiz, Try now.

Comment: I am still getting the same error Key Object_list expected Parcelable but value was a java.util.ArrayList.

Comment: Just check that _Listitem_ implements with `Parcable` or `Serializable` @Moudiz

Comment: this is the class public `class Listitem implements Parcelable {`

Comment: nop it didnt work either `this.listObjects = (Listitem) extras.getParcelableArrayList(OBJECT_LIST);` or `this.listObjects =  extras.getParcelableArrayList(OBJECT_LIST);` cannot cast parcalable to listitem

Comment: When you put objects in intent it should be parcable not string. This is _personArrayList_ so you need to get in arrayList.  It will be             this.Objects= (ArrayList<Listitem>)extras.getParcelableArrayList(OBJECT_LIST); @Moudiz

Comment: @Piyush sorry i didnt understand , check my edit for how i am sending them

Comment: @Piyush we can use putExtra there is nothing wrong in it.

Comment: @Moudiz Now you got it... I think

Answer (score 0):

1.Make you model class i.e. ListItem Parcelable

2.
in second step,

`Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("list",list);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);`

3.
ArrayList list = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("list");

Answer (score 0):

In sending intent code `intent.putExtra("Object_list", personArrayList);`  replace with this `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Object_list", personArrayList);` will solve problem